# script command does not wait for child if running with nohup

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If we run a command such as

```
time script -c 'sleep 5'

0.00user 0.00system 0:05.00elapsed
```

This takes 5 seconds+ to complete as expected.

```
time nohup sleep 5

0.00user 0.00system 0:05.00elapsed
```

This also takes 5 seconds+ to complete as expected

```
time nohup script -c 'sleep 5'

0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed
```

This however takes < 1 second to complete. It looks like nohup and script don't play well together. The script command returns immediately after creating the child instead of waiting for the child to complete.

I have not been able to find any explanation as to why this is happening, and how to get it to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can check the contents of nohup.out from where you executed nohup command, you can see the output of `script` if there's any(Applicable to the 3rd case).

Answer (score 0):

nohup makes the command to run in the background and thats why the command (3rd) is returning as you press enter.
See this [page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html) for more details